# how to stop and resume jenkins service

Tags: selenium, jenkins, automation

I got confused, how to stop/start the Jenkins after I have installed jenkins.war on my terminal with this script

> java -jar jenkins.war -httpPort=8080

cause if run above code again, could be error cause port already in use. I can uninstall it, but it's like wasting time if I need Jenkins I must uninstall it and then install again. **need someone that knows how to stop/start command without uninstall the installed jenkins**

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you have administrative right you should be able to access the following URL. Just confirm the restart.

```
http://<Jenkins_IP>/restart
```

Answer (score 0):

i would explain the step, i install my jenkins as admin

1. http://localhost:8080/exit [login to jenkins first]
2. close your terminal
3. open your terminal and go to your directory .war file
4. run java -jar jenkins.war -httpPort=8080
5. http://localhost:8080/restart